# Как автоматически отправить форму при нажатии на чекбокс?

Tags: javascript

Как автоматически отправить форму при нажатии на чекбокс?

Comment: Маловато информации. Пример кода на jsfiddle выложите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов много:

```
$('#checkbox_id').on('change', function(){
      $('#form_id').submit();
   });
});
```

Можно на `click` повесить:

```
 $('#checkbox_id').on('click', function(){
    ...
 });
```

Можно задать атрибут у чекбокса:

```
<input type="checkbox_id" onchange="$('#form_id').submit();"  name="checkbox" />
```